# Is it possible to release an app only for iPhone 6s and 6s+?

Tags: ios, 3dtouch

I am working on an app whose core functionaltiy lies in features that are only supported in the newer 6s and 6s+ devices, such as 3D touch. Is there a way to submit and relase the app on the app store only to those devices, or do I have to make it so that it has value for all iPhone models?

Update:

There is a "required device capibilities" key, but I couldn't find anything that I can include there related to 3D Touch capibility. See [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: NOTE

3D Touch is available only on 3D Touch devices and when enabled. In iOS 9, 3D Touch is enabled by default. A user can turn off 3D Touch in Settings > General > Accessibility > 3D Touch.

Answer (score 2):

Apple goes by the iOS version and the platform type (iPhone, iPad), so you can specify iOS 9 and iPhone, but you will still need to support models that can run iOS 9 but doesn't have the hardware capabilities of the new phones.  I had an app rejected because it wouldn't support iPhone 4s when I released on iOS 8.

Answer (score -2):

You can check for 3D Touch available when app starts, if the device doesn't have it then show an alert dialog and do nothing at all.

Comment: yea i did that but my concern is that it would get rejected for not doing anything - you're app needs to do something...